# Need to save a file without the repeating same name or overwrite a file name

Tags: python

I want to save video file as Summary_1.mp4 ,summary_2.mp4 ....for n files without overwrite How can i do that ,

```
parser.add_argument('--save-name', type=str, default='final_summary.mp4', help="(ends with .mp4)") 
parser.add_argument('--save-dir', type=str, default='log', help="directory to save")
        args = parser.parse_args() 
          def frm2video(frm_dir, summary,save_name):
        
        if not osp.exists(args.save_dir):       
            vid_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(osp.join(args.save_dir,args.save_name),     
            cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'),args.fps,(args.width, args.height))       
           
            h5_res = h5py.File(args.dataset, 'r')     
            # summary = frame_num_binary
            h5_res.close()
            # frm2video(args.frm_dir, summary, vid_writer)
            vid_writer.release()
```

Comment: You can use For loops

Comment: Of course. But you know how to save .mp4 files right?

Comment: Look at my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this example with **.txt** files -

```
for i in range(1,21): # This will repeat for 20 times, you can change it.
    file = f'Summary_{i}.txt' # Save files like - Summary_1 ... Summary_20
    f = open(file,'w')
    f.write(f'This is file {i}') # file 1 ... 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a unique portion of the filename to avoid overwriting.  Ways to get something unique include:

1. use a counter that you increment until you are done saving files, as BCM posted.

unique_counter = 0

save the next file, then increment the counter

unique_counter += 1

2. use a timestamp.  Depending on how quickly you save each file, use the timestamp down to the microsecond. Format the timestamp to be legal for use in filenames, e.g., don't use : and maybe you don't want spaces or periods.  In the examples below, I use _ as the separator character between year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond.

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp_down_to_microseconds = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_%f")
# '2021_06_25_23_31_40_068571'

timestamp_down_to_seconds = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
# '2021_06_25_23_31_40'

timestamp_down_to_minutes = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M")
# '2021_06_25_23_31'
```